# Error: "Couldn't set ssl mode"

Tags: npgsql

I'm trying to set the `SSL Mode` in my connection string:

```
SSL Mode=preferred;
```

But I'm getting an `ArgumentException` when my code tries to connect to the database:

[image: Exception info showing an ArgumentException with message "Couldn't set ssl mode. Parameter name: ssl mode". InnerException message is "Requested value 'preferred' was not found.".]

Notice that the `InnerException`, says:

> Requested value 'preferred' was not found.

Looking at the following documentation, it should be valid to specify `required`, `disabled` or `preferred`:

- [Npgsql Connection String Parameters](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html)
- [Npgsql Security and Encryption](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html)

I'm using Npgsql 3.0.3, which I obtained using NuGet:

[image: NuGet showing Npgsql 3.0.3 installed]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it turns out that you actually need to specify *verb* values rather than *adjectives*:

- `Disable`
- `Prefer`
- `Require`

For example:

```
SSL Mode=Prefer;
```

**Edit**: [the documentation has since been corrected](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/873#issuecomment-161039041).

Comment: @RaidenCore, fair enough. I've just updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Add **sslmode=Require;** and **Trust Server Certificate=true;** as it is in your connection string.It will work for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The following values are allowed when setting the Ssl Mode:

Npgsql v6.0+:

- Disable
- Allow
- Prefer (default)
- Require
- VerifyCA
- VerifyFull

Npgsql pre-v6.0:

- Disable (default)
- Prefer
- Require

The default values denote which setting is selected if the Ssl Mode is not specified.

Link to documentation:
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html#encryption-ssltls

The value for the Ssl Mode setting also appears to be case sensitive.

An example taken from a log file when '**p**refer' was used instead of '**P**refer':

```
Exception Type: System.ArgumentException
Exception Messsage: Couldn't set ssl mode, Parameter name: ssl mode
InnerException Messsage: Requested value 'prefer' was not found.
```

*Note: the above log was from a DotNet Core 2.1 app using Npgsql 4.0.3 (so the case sensitivity claim for v4.1+ may no longer be relevant)*

Whilst the value was found to be case sensitive, the setting itself was not (i.e. **s**sl **m**ode vs **S**sl **M**ode work the same); e.g.

```
Server=localhost;Port=5432;ssl mode='Prefer';...
```

and

```
Server=localhost;Port=5432;Ssl Mode='Prefer';...
```

both worked fine.

**An aside:**

It would appear that pre-v3.0 'Allow' was a valid setting, as the v3.0 release notes state that it was removed;
see https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/3.0.html#ssl.

Presumably, it was reintroduced in v.6.0 again when Npgsql was aligned with the PostgreSQL standard;
see https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/6.0.html#ssltls-improvements.

Additional from the v6.0 release notes:

*The default SSL Mode is now Prefer*;
see https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/6.0.html#the-default-ssl-mode-is-now-prefer

*Changes to SSL configuration (SSL Mode=Require)*;
see https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/6.0.html#changes-to-ssl-configuration-ssl-moderequire